# How to fix nodejs installation process on linux 19.04

Tags: 19.04, nodejs

Running on my system Ububntu 19.04 i find difficulty in installing nodejs

After running `sudo apt install nodejs`

I got the below errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2 libnode64 libuv1 nodejs-doc
Suggested packages:
  npm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2 libnode64 libuv1 nodejs nodejs-doc
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 143 not upgraded.
Need to get 6452 kB/6489 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 libuv1 amd64 1.24.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:2 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 libnode64 amd64 10.15.2~dfsg-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Ign:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 nodejs-doc all 10.15.2~dfsg-1
Err:4 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 nodejs amd64 10.15.2~dfsg-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 nodejs-doc all 10.15.2~dfsg-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libuv1/libuv1_1.24.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nodejs/libnode64_10.15.2~dfsg-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nodejs/nodejs-doc_10.15.2~dfsg-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nodejs/nodejs_10.15.2~dfsg-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What is going wrong? How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Why try reaching your nose by going around the back of your head, instead of reaching straight up?
Here is how you can fix it. Head over to nodejs.org and download the stable version. Click that big green button where it says the LTS version. Once downloaded, right-click to see the option. Select the 'Open with Archive Manager' option. It will extract the file to your Download folder. 
Now go to the 'software center' (with the 'shopping bag' icon) and search for Node or Node JS. You will find the Node JS the familiar green Node JS icon. Click to install and launch. That's it.
Launch terminal and type "node --version". You will see the version number.
You have installed Node.js in your system.